# How to remove write permission to a folder using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system, chmod

How can i remove write permission to a specific folder using python?

I have tried these codes below but with no success:

```
os.chmod(path, mode=0o777)

os.chmod(path, stat.S_IRUSR | stat.S_IRGRP | stat.S_IROTH)
```

How can i make it so when i open the permission section to that folder it will appear like this:

[image: Example]

Comment: I think you should use 0o555 instead of 0o777

Comment: Hey @kamyarmg, tried that but it is not working